# Python asynchronous request handling while calling subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, tornado, popen

I have a REST API written in Flask and using the Tornado web server.

When a request comes in, I execute a long running shell command using `tornado.process.Subprocess`.

Is there a way to keep handling new requests while the shell command is running, and return the result after the shell command is complete.

I am thinking

```
from tornado import gen
from tornado.process import Subprocess

@gen.coroutine
def callSubProcess(commandString):
    p = Subprocess(commandString)
    yield p.wait_for_exit()
    raise gen.Return(someResult)

@app.route(url, methods=['POST'])
@gen.coroutine
def process():
    result = yield callSubProcess(commandString)
    raise gen.Return(result)

http_server = HTTPServer(WSGIContainer(app))
http_server.listen(5000)
IOLoop.instance().start()
```

But this doesn't seem to work:
I just get `'Future' object is not callable` when making a request.  What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/celery/celery is exactly what you need,

Celery allows you to execute the shell command asynchronously thus you'll be able to handle all coming requests.

Answer (score 0):

To use coroutines, you must use `tornado.web.Application`, not `tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer`. Tornado does not magically give WSGI frameworks like Flask the ability to handle asynchronous operations and coroutines.

Comment: I have my routes setup in Flask, is it still possible to use Tornado's non-blocking asynchronous framework?

Comment: No, it is not. See the [warning](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html#tornado.wsgi.WSGIContainer) on the WSGIContainer docs; Tornado's WSGIContainer is only useful in limited circumstances. To use the asynchronous parts of Tornado, you need to use Tornado for the whole stack.